# Flask-Admin/SQLAchemy: Standard idiom to produce a row-filtered user view

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

Using SQLAlchemy through Flask-Admin/Flask-Security.
I have 2 roles: "admin" and "user"
Normal users own certain parts of the data (certain rows of the tables) and should only access their own data.

1. What is the standard idiom only allowing users to access their data but not other users' data? I created a special UserView and overrode get_query and get_count_query and included a filter in these methods. Is that the standard way?
2. I am new to SLQAlchemy, and I am having trouble filtering tables that are "distant" from the User table.
   For example: User to Project (many-to-one), Project to X (many-to-many), X to Y (many-to-many), all with backrefs.
   How would I filter in the Y view for a non-admin user to filter only those rows that are reachable from the current user (through Project)?
   Thanks!

Comment: how did you solve this?  I have the same problem